# Graficar en C# con datos de Datagridview

Tags: c#

Hola podrian asesorarme o darme ideas de como trabajar con esto, lo que necesito es insertar un valor numérico en el textbox y que este valor se inserte dentro de el DataGridView se inserte en la columna valor y en donde dice clave se vaya auto incrementando el numero y así mismo se vayan mostrando los datos en un control Chart.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para el flujo de trabajo me parece evidente

**1. Crear un evento en el botón Agregar...**

Da doble clic al botón Aceptar para crear un método automáticamente.

```
private void btnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Todo el código en éste método se ejecutará cada vez que presiones el botón Agregar. Aquí haremos lo del siguiente punto...

**2. Inserta el valor del TextBox en el DataGridView...**

Sería bueno que aquí (en el método del botón) validaras que el valor del TextBox no esté vacío, que no tenga letras, etc.

Inserta en el DataGridView una nueva fila con el índice, y el valor que está en el TextBox así como te indicaron en otra respuesta

```
this.midataGridView.Rows.Add(claveSiguiente, textBoxValor.Text);
```

Dentro de éste mismo método del botón agregas el valor del TextBox a la gráfica de barras

```
mibarChart1.Series[0].Points.Add(Convert.ToInt32(textBoxValor.Text));
```

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48193/discussion-between-karolprincess-and-freddy-hdz).

Answer (score 1):

Como veo en la imagen solo tienes dos columnas en tu DataGridView, cuando quieras agregar, tienes que agregar toda la fila aunque sea un dato vació de la siguiente forma.

```
     miDataGrid.Rows.Add(mitextbox.Text, mitextbox2.Text);
```

Con esto agregar reglones a tu DataGridView.

Comment: pero ... solo tengo un textbox y si agrego un numero me lo agrega en las dos columnas el mismo numero